# Jasmine fixtures: problems in setting path

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm using jasmine framework with jquery and I need to load fixtures from a specific path. Here is my folder structure:

```
E:  
  - project  
    - app
      - views         //FIXTURE FILES HERE IN THIS FOLDER
        - main.html  
    - public  
        - scripts
            - library 
              - jasmine-standalone  
                 - SpecRunner.html //JASMINE SPECRUNNER
            - specs              //CHANGED PATH OF JASMINE'S SPEC FOLDER  
                - testSpecs.js   //FILE WHERE I NEED TO LOAD FIXTURES  
            test.js            //CONTAINS CODE I NEED TO TEST (included in SpecRunner)
```

Now, I've changed the path of specs as shown, but I included that in SpecRunner and it works fine, as my tests are getting run. I now need to load main.html as a fixture to testSpecs. How would I do that? Here's what i tried:

In testSpecs.js:

```
describe("Login Form", function() {

    beforeEach(function(){
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "/../../../app/views"; //(EDIT NEEDED HERE)
        jasmine.getFixtures().load('main.html');
    });
```

In SpecRunner.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.1.3</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.1.3/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.1.3/jasmine.css">

  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.1.3/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.1.3/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.1.3/boot.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jasmine-jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>


  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="../../test.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script src="../../specs/testSpecs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

PS - Can I incude .php files in fixture?